# When do the experiments of the archimedes project start?

Tags: quantum-gravity, virtual-particles, casimir-effect

I am talking about the archimedes project, in which the gravitational effect of vacuum fluctuations will be tested using Casimir plates.
https://cerncourier.com/a/scoping-out-the-einstein-telescope/

Comment: They are working on the detectors  https://inspirehep.net/literature/2151736